# How to add files and folders to program directory in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, path, installation

I'm writing a winforms application in C#. I want to have some folders (and potentially some files) always in my program's ('install') directory which I will be using in the application. Potentially moving these when I deploy the app on different machines. I also need these to be present when I am writing, compiling and testing the programme obviously.

How can I do this without writing code to create these folders on programme startup?

Comment: Right click in solution explorer and add folder ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add whatever files you want to work with in your project  and then set the

`Copy to Output Directory` property of the files to `Copy always` option.

so that the files willbe always copied to your output directory either `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` and you can always access them.

Comment: And don't forget to set the `Build Action` to `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a directory, go to Project->Properties->Build Events and add this:

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)Resources\MyDir" "$(TargetDir)\MyDir\" /S /Y
```

"/S" will copy files recursively, and "/Y" will overwrite without prompt.